# Amf PHP stateless?

Tags: actionscript-3, amfphp

Is amfPHP stateless? In case it is, is there a way to make it stateless. If there is, what would be the ideal way to implement security over amfphp ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AmfPHP is stateless - each request is independent and unrelated to any previous request.

AMF is just a format like JSON or XML, it doesn't have any built-in security. You implement security like you do for any other web application - OAuth, SSL, etc.